# CEWP text allign

Tags: cewp

I have a Table (just 2 columns, 1 row) in CEWP. The first column holds 3 paragraph of text and 2nd column Image.

The image length is longer than the paragraph but thats not the issue. The issue is paragraph is now middle center. Is there a way to align Top - Left?

Comment: could u share a snapshot of it and its html part?

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding you could use valign='top' as below example:

```
<td valign="top">
```

and also check for the CSS applied on the paragraph element. The CSS of p might be overridden.